# Serializing object graph using MongoDB Bson serializer

Tags: serialization, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I've been playing a little with the MongoDB Bson serializer, using the following piece of code:

```
class Program
{
    public class myValue
    {
        public int Id = 0;
        public string Label = "";
    }

    public class myValueMap : Dictionary<string, myValue>
    {
    }

    public class myProdData
    {
        public myValueMap  Mapping { get; set; }

    }
    public class mySystemPosition
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public myProdData ProdData { get; set; }

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<mySystemPosition>();
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<myProdData>();
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<myValueMap>();
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<myValue>();
        var o = new mySystemPosition()
                    {
                        ProdData = new myProdData()
                                       {
                                           Mapping = new myValueMap()
                                                        {
                                                            {"123", new myValue() {Id = 1, Label = "Item1"}},
                                                            {"345", new myValue() {Id = 2, Label = "Item2"}},
                                                        }
                                       }
                    };
        var bson = o.ToBson();

        var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bson);
    }
}
```

however I don't seem to be able to get the myProdData.Mapping serialized....

Do I need to configure the MongoDB Bson serializer in a special way, to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You no need to use `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap` if you no need custom serializtion([documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial)).
All your classes will be desirialzied according to default rules.

Also i am changed your example a little bit to get it work(i've replaces `myValueMap` class with Dictionary):

```
    public class myProdData
    {
        public  Dictionary<string, myValue> Mapping { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new mySystemPosition()
        {
            ProdData = new myProdData()
            {
                Mapping = new Dictionary<string, myValue>()
                {
                    {"123", new myValue() {Id = 1, Label = "Item1"}},
                    {"345", new myValue() {Id = 2, Label = "Item2"}},
                }
            }
        };

        var json = o.ToJson();
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Here is console output(just well formatted):

```
{
    "Text":null,
    "ProdData":{
        "Mapping":{
            "123":{
                "_id":1,
                "Label":"Item1"
            },
            "345":{
                "_id":2,
                "Label":"Item2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can test your serializtion using `ToJson()` extention method, in order to view that all correct and after that use `ToBson()` if need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that myValueMap derives from Dictionary. That results in a class that the AutoMap method can't handle.

I recommend you just use the Dictionary directly, as Andrew did in his reply.

Answer (score 0):

Ufortunately the myValueMap is an object that I can't easily change, however it turns out, that's pretty easy to create your own (de)serializer....

```
    public class myValueMapSerializer : IBsonSerializer
    {
        public object Deserialize(Bson.IO.BsonReader bsonReader, System.Type nominalType, System.Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
        {
            if (nominalType != typeof(myValueMap)) throw new ArgumentException("Cannot serialize anything but myValueMap");
            var res = new myValueMap();
            var ser = new DictionarySerializer<string, myValue>();
            var dic = (Dictionary<string, myValue>)ser.Deserialize(bsonReader, typeof(Dictionary<string, myValue>), options);

            foreach (var item in dic)
            {
                res.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
            return res;
        }

        public object Deserialize(Bson.IO.BsonReader bsonReader, System.Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not implemented");
        }

        public bool GetDocumentId(object document, out object id, out IIdGenerator idGenerator)
        {
            id = null;
            idGenerator = null;
            return false;
        }

        public void Serialize(Bson.IO.BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
        {
            if (nominalType != typeof(myValueMap)) throw new ArgumentException("Cannot serialize anything but myValueMap");

            var ser = new DictionarySerializer<string, myValue>();
            ser.Serialize(bsonWriter, typeof(DictionarySerializer<string, myValue>), value, options);
        }

        public void SetDocumentId(object document, object id)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a good solution. I would throw a NotSupportedException from GetDocumentId and SetDocumentId though. They're not supposed to be called for anything but the root document, and you'd probably rather find out about it if they were rather than failing silently.